# Model detection with Hololens2 using Vuforia plugin and overlay animations on detected models

Tags: vuforia

I want to develop a project using Vuforia for 3D model detection for real time car components and overlay animations on top of the detected car components. Can this be possible using Vuforia?

Tried Using Vuforia Model Generator and imported the models into Unity, but not sure which code must be used for this.

Comment: I'd suggest to go through the Core Samples or VFX Library of Vuforia Engine within the Unity Asset Store to find out more pointers how to develop such an AR experience.